# PCI gigabit (tp-link TG-3269) and PCIe gigabit (TP-Link tg-3468)

Tags: networking, router, pci-express, wired-networking

I need help as my PC has few NICS. 
I notice that TG-3269 can reach only **60-80 MBytes/s (tested using NetIO)** but PCI express (TG-3468) always **above 100 MBytes/s, even upto 110 MBytes/s**

Is that normal ? All cables are Cat6.

I tried to relocate cables between ports to isolate cabling problem, but for 1M (only 1 meter length) i don't think cable is problem

All cables that goes to PCIe always perform above 100 Mbytes/s (tested using NetIO)

Is that normal ? PCI gigabit is 1/2 speed of PCIe gigabit ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pci is 33mhz x 32 bits(4 bytes) = 133MB/s. Also keep in mind pci bus bandwidth is shared across all devices accessing the bus. So it really depends on your motherboards bus speed, and how many other Pci devices are connected to the bus. Pci-e has a much higher amount of bandwidth across the different versions.

v1.x 250 MB/s
v2.x 500 MB/s
v3.0 985 MB/s
v4.0 1969 MB/s

Just Google "pci vs pci-e" if you need more info.
https://www.naplestech.com/bus-speeds.html

Comment: You are almost certainly correct in your answer because 99% of consumer PCI devices are 33Mhzx32bit. However there are also 64 bit PCI-e cards, 66MHz PCIe cards and 64bit@66MHz PCI-e cards. I have used the latter in a nice Tyan motherboard with a dual gigabit NIC. Outside server/ws system it was rare though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the comment. I was not aware of 64bit versions of PCI.